Why doesn't a relative route work in my routes.js file?
I am trying to make some code as reusable as possible, so it is easy to create a new version of the code to experiment with.
Can anyone explain to me why this works;
router.post('/baseline/auth/create-email-sms', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('create-checkemail')
})

But this doesn't?
router.post('../auth/create-email-sms', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('create-checkemail')
})

Essentially, I want to be able to make a copy of "baseline" and rename it, and not have to go through all my routes and change the name in the file path.
When I use the relative path, it says there is nothing at /baseline/auth/create-email-sms, when it should be redirecting to create-checkemail
Thanks!

Creating a variable works to solve this;
const parentDir = '/baseline'

router.post(`${parentDir}/auth/create-email-sms`, function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('create-checkemail')
})

Now I only need to change the parentDir variable on each routes page.


Route paths, in combination with a request method, define the endpoints at which requests can be made. Route paths can be strings, string patterns, or regular expressions.

Citation: Route paths
Therefore the following code using string pattern may be an option for you.
router.post('/*/auth/create-email-sms', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('create-checkemail');
});

Testing the route path:
% curl http://localhost:3000/baseline/auth/create-email-sms -X POST
 
Found. Redirecting to create-checkemail                                  

% curl http://localhost:3000/route1/auth/create-email-sms -X POST

Found. Redirecting to create-checkemail                                  

% curl http://localhost:3000/route2/auth/create-email-sms -X POST  

Found. Redirecting to create-checkemail                                  


Hi, Was this post of any help to your question?
